# Possible Large Can of Worms With Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, root, devices

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and recently had a problem where my computer wouldn't register any device, integrated keyboard or mouse or otherwise, as soon as the login screen loaded. Once it loaded, my cursor would not appear, the password field has a blinking line as if I can type but my keyboard is unresponsive, and even that stops blinking and everything freezes after a couple seconds. I've tried using the alternate kernals in the Grub menu but they all reproduce the same problem. When I go to recovery, I can't successfully clean, enable networking, dkgp, or use any commands successfully within the root file. As an example, no command involving fetching things from the Ubuntu page is ever successful. I deleted Windows when I installed Ubuntu, and am wondering if starting over with a new installation of this OS is the correct move. I have the ISO on my jump drive. If we can't find a solution to my problem, how would I reinstall this version of Ubuntu? Thanks for your help in advanced

Edit:
The hardware I'm using is a Dell Latitude with an Intel Core i5 Processor and an Intel HD Graphics video controller, and some version of an amd64 Nvidia card. CPU is telling me the number 86 is related but I'm not sure what that means. This is all I can find without being able to make any commands work in the root terminal. I apologize for any information missing. I'm not 100% sure what you need to solve the problem and that's partially why I suggested a full reinstall.

Edit #2:
Ok, so it seems that the missing drivers will be installed using the dkpg option on grub. However, I keep getting an error that seems to be revolving around the lack of a resolv.conf file. Any ideas how to replace or create it through the Grub root terminal? This should solve my above problem

Comment: Can we please know about the hardware specifics? Please [edit] and post it. It probably needs just a few additional steps like booting with `nomodeset` and install graphics drivers.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/resolv.conf lists the DNS servers to query when resolving domain names (typically a server) to their respective IP addresses.

For more information:

man resolv.conf

To create/edit this file (with root privileges):

vi /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx # IP of first DNS server to query

nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx # IP of second DNS server to query

Up to three DNS servers can be placed in this list

:wq! # write file and exit

NOTE: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx would typically be the DNS server addresses provided by your ISP.  Some prefer to use OpenDNS servers which are currently 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220

Comment: Considering my situation, what would you suggest I fill in the blanks with?